# ¿Como obtener la cantidad de veces que se repite un valor en un array?

Tags: javascript

Necesito saber cuantas veces se repite cada una de las partes, la llave única de cada una es el `id` que tiene cada `array` dentro de los `array`.

Actualmente solo imprimo los nombres pero no encuentro como hacer un contador para cada parte.

```js
var array = [
    [
      49,
      [
        {
          "id": "310",
          "nombre": "Placas",
          "id_padre": "309"
        },
        {
          "id": "311",
          "nombre": "Inferior",
          "id_padre": "310"
        },
        {
          "id": "312",
          "nombre": "Superior",
          "id_padre": "310"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      48,
      [
        {
          "id": "341",
          "nombre": "Sistema de Descarte",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "342",
          "nombre": "Dedos de Retension",
          "id_padre": "341"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      47,
      [
        {
          "id": "334",
          "nombre": "Sistema de Refrigeracion",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "310",
          "nombre": "Placas",
          "id_padre": "309"
        },
        {
          "id": "314",
          "nombre": "Muelles",
          "id_padre": "309"
        },
        {
          "id": "311",
          "nombre": "Inferior",
          "id_padre": "310"
        },
        {
          "id": "312",
          "nombre": "Superior",
          "id_padre": "310"
        },
        {
          "id": "338",
          "nombre": "Condensadora",
          "id_padre": "334"
        },
        {
          "id": "335",
          "nombre": "Compresor",
          "id_padre": "334"
        },
        {
          "id": "336",
          "nombre": "Evaporador",
          "id_padre": "334"
        },
        {
          "id": "337",
          "nombre": "Partes Electricas",
          "id_padre": "334"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      46,
      [
        {
          "id": "8",
          "nombre": "Placas",
          "id_padre": "1"
        },
        {
          "id": "305",
          "nombre": "Superior ",
          "id_padre": "8"
        },
        {
          "id": "306",
          "nombre": "Inferior",
          "id_padre": "8"
        },
        {
          "id": "310",
          "nombre": "Placas",
          "id_padre": "309"
        },
        {
          "id": "311",
          "nombre": "Inferior",
          "id_padre": "310"
        },
        {
          "id": "312",
          "nombre": "Superior",
          "id_padre": "310"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      45,
      [
        {
          "id": "341",
          "nombre": "Sistema de Descarte",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "342",
          "nombre": "Dedos de Retension",
          "id_padre": "341"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      44,
      [
        {
          "id": "305",
          "nombre": "Superior ",
          "id_padre": "8"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      36,
      [
        {
          "id": "339",
          "nombre": "Sistema de Deteccion",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "340",
          "nombre": "Camaras",
          "id_padre": "339"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      26,
      [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "nombre": "Estación de Formación",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "306",
          "nombre": "Inferior",
          "id_padre": "8"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      25,
      [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "nombre": "Estación de Formación",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "339",
          "nombre": "Sistema de Deteccion",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "340",
          "nombre": "Camaras",
          "id_padre": "339"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      24,
      [
        {
          "id": "339",
          "nombre": "Sistema de Deteccion",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "340",
          "nombre": "Camaras",
          "id_padre": "339"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      23,
      [
        {
          "id": "339",
          "nombre": "Sistema de Deteccion",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "340",
          "nombre": "Camaras",
          "id_padre": "339"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      22,
      [
        {
          "id": "339",
          "nombre": "Sistema de Deteccion",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "340",
          "nombre": "Camaras",
          "id_padre": "339"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      21,
      [
        {
          "id": "339",
          "nombre": "Sistema de Deteccion",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "340",
          "nombre": "Camaras",
          "id_padre": "339"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      20,
      [
        {
          "id": "4",
          "nombre": "Estación de Calentamiento",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "339",
          "nombre": "Sistema de Deteccion",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "7",
          "nombre": "Placas",
          "id_padre": "4"
        },
        {
          "id": "9",
          "nombre": "Superior",
          "id_padre": "7"
        },
        {
          "id": "10",
          "nombre": "Inferior",
          "id_padre": "7"
        },
        {
          "id": "340",
          "nombre": "Camaras",
          "id_padre": "339"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      19,
      [
        {
          "id": "339",
          "nombre": "Sistema de Deteccion",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "340",
          "nombre": "Camaras",
          "id_padre": "339"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      18,
      [
        {
          "id": "339",
          "nombre": "Sistema de Deteccion",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "340",
          "nombre": "Camaras",
          "id_padre": "339"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      17,
      [
        {
          "id": "339",
          "nombre": "Sistema de Deteccion",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "340",
          "nombre": "Camaras",
          "id_padre": "339"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      16,
      [
        {
          "id": "309",
          "nombre": "Estación de Sellado",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "310",
          "nombre": "Placas",
          "id_padre": "309"
        },
        {
          "id": "316",
          "nombre": "Resortes",
          "id_padre": "309"
        },
        {
          "id": "315",
          "nombre": "Leva",
          "id_padre": "309"
        },
        {
          "id": "313",
          "nombre": "Esparragos",
          "id_padre": "309"
        },
        {
          "id": "314",
          "nombre": "Muelles",
          "id_padre": "309"
        },
        {
          "id": "312",
          "nombre": "Superior",
          "id_padre": "310"
        },
        {
          "id": "311",
          "nombre": "Inferior",
          "id_padre": "310"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      15,
      [
        {
          "id": "309",
          "nombre": "Estación de Sellado",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "310",
          "nombre": "Placas",
          "id_padre": "309"
        },
        {
          "id": "311",
          "nombre": "Inferior",
          "id_padre": "310"
        },
        {
          "id": "312",
          "nombre": "Superior",
          "id_padre": "310"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      14,
      [
        {
          "id": "334",
          "nombre": "Sistema de Refrigeracion",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "337",
          "nombre": "Partes Electricas",
          "id_padre": "334"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      13,
      [
        {
          "id": "317",
          "nombre": "Estación de Corte",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "320",
          "nombre": "Ventosas",
          "id_padre": "317"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      12,
      [
        {
          "id": "317",
          "nombre": "Estación de Corte",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "320",
          "nombre": "Ventosas",
          "id_padre": "317"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      11,
      [
        {
          "id": "320",
          "nombre": "Ventosas",
          "id_padre": "317"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ]
  ]
;

//console.log(array);

let array_listado = [];
for(n in array){
    let conteo = 0;
    let array_prin = array[n][1];
    for(j in array_prin){
        let id_parte = parseInt(array_prin[j].id);
        console.log('id_parte: '+id_parte);
        let result = false;
        for(l in array_listado){
            if(array_listado[l].id === id_parte){
                result = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!result){
            array_listado.push({id: id_parte,nombre: array_prin[j].nombre,conteo: 0,});
        }else{
          //aca no se q hacer :/
          //se supone que debo buscar el elemento y sumarle 1 al contador
        }
    }
}
console.log(array_listado);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: yo, a grandes rasgos, crearía un vector/lista por cada elemento que obtienes, y luego recorrería tu array, agregando cada elemento a su vector/lista correspondiente, evaluando, si es un valor existente en la lista, que sume 1 a un contador de repetidos por elemento, caso contrario, que lo agregue a la lista.

Comment: @PabloContreras ¿Lo que quieres es obtener todos los id repetidos, los nombres repetidos y los id_padre repetidos? Es decir, el contador de cada uno de ellos.

Comment: @FranciscoRomero si hermano, exactamente. Aunque el **id_padre** no es de mi interes.

Comment: en la parte donde no sabes que hacer, sólo es recorrer la lista del elemento en cuestión, comparando que cada elemento que tiene la lista no se repita, *un for que recorra tu lista*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En un objeto que llame contador guardo como propiedad cada uno de los ID de tu arreglo, si no existe el ID lo inicializo con 1, si existe incremento su valor, al final recorro todas las propiedades del contador (que son los ID contados) y los imprimo

```js
var array = [
    [
      49,
      [
        {
          "id": "310",
          "nombre": "Placas",
          "id_padre": "309"
        },
        {
          "id": "311",
          "nombre": "Inferior",
          "id_padre": "310"
        },
        {
          "id": "312",
          "nombre": "Superior",
          "id_padre": "310"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      48,
      [
        {
          "id": "341",
          "nombre": "Sistema de Descarte",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "342",
          "nombre": "Dedos de Retension",
          "id_padre": "341"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      47,
      [
        {
          "id": "334",
          "nombre": "Sistema de Refrigeracion",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "310",
          "nombre": "Placas",
          "id_padre": "309"
        },
        {
          "id": "314",
          "nombre": "Muelles",
          "id_padre": "309"
        },
        {
          "id": "311",
          "nombre": "Inferior",
          "id_padre": "310"
        },
        {
          "id": "312",
          "nombre": "Superior",
          "id_padre": "310"
        },
        {
          "id": "338",
          "nombre": "Condensadora",
          "id_padre": "334"
        },
        {
          "id": "335",
          "nombre": "Compresor",
          "id_padre": "334"
        },
        {
          "id": "336",
          "nombre": "Evaporador",
          "id_padre": "334"
        },
        {
          "id": "337",
          "nombre": "Partes Electricas",
          "id_padre": "334"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      46,
      [
        {
          "id": "8",
          "nombre": "Placas",
          "id_padre": "1"
        },
        {
          "id": "305",
          "nombre": "Superior ",
          "id_padre": "8"
        },
        {
          "id": "306",
          "nombre": "Inferior",
          "id_padre": "8"
        },
        {
          "id": "310",
          "nombre": "Placas",
          "id_padre": "309"
        },
        {
          "id": "311",
          "nombre": "Inferior",
          "id_padre": "310"
        },
        {
          "id": "312",
          "nombre": "Superior",
          "id_padre": "310"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      45,
      [
        {
          "id": "341",
          "nombre": "Sistema de Descarte",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "342",
          "nombre": "Dedos de Retension",
          "id_padre": "341"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      44,
      [
        {
          "id": "305",
          "nombre": "Superior ",
          "id_padre": "8"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      36,
      [
        {
          "id": "339",
          "nombre": "Sistema de Deteccion",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "340",
          "nombre": "Camaras",
          "id_padre": "339"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      26,
      [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "nombre": "Estación de Formación",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "306",
          "nombre": "Inferior",
          "id_padre": "8"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      25,
      [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "nombre": "Estación de Formación",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "339",
          "nombre": "Sistema de Deteccion",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "340",
          "nombre": "Camaras",
          "id_padre": "339"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      24,
      [
        {
          "id": "339",
          "nombre": "Sistema de Deteccion",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "340",
          "nombre": "Camaras",
          "id_padre": "339"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      23,
      [
        {
          "id": "339",
          "nombre": "Sistema de Deteccion",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "340",
          "nombre": "Camaras",
          "id_padre": "339"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      22,
      [
        {
          "id": "339",
          "nombre": "Sistema de Deteccion",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "340",
          "nombre": "Camaras",
          "id_padre": "339"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      21,
      [
        {
          "id": "339",
          "nombre": "Sistema de Deteccion",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "340",
          "nombre": "Camaras",
          "id_padre": "339"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      20,
      [
        {
          "id": "4",
          "nombre": "Estación de Calentamiento",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "339",
          "nombre": "Sistema de Deteccion",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "7",
          "nombre": "Placas",
          "id_padre": "4"
        },
        {
          "id": "9",
          "nombre": "Superior",
          "id_padre": "7"
        },
        {
          "id": "10",
          "nombre": "Inferior",
          "id_padre": "7"
        },
        {
          "id": "340",
          "nombre": "Camaras",
          "id_padre": "339"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      19,
      [
        {
          "id": "339",
          "nombre": "Sistema de Deteccion",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "340",
          "nombre": "Camaras",
          "id_padre": "339"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      18,
      [
        {
          "id": "339",
          "nombre": "Sistema de Deteccion",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "340",
          "nombre": "Camaras",
          "id_padre": "339"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      17,
      [
        {
          "id": "339",
          "nombre": "Sistema de Deteccion",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "340",
          "nombre": "Camaras",
          "id_padre": "339"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      16,
      [
        {
          "id": "309",
          "nombre": "Estación de Sellado",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "310",
          "nombre": "Placas",
          "id_padre": "309"
        },
        {
          "id": "316",
          "nombre": "Resortes",
          "id_padre": "309"
        },
        {
          "id": "315",
          "nombre": "Leva",
          "id_padre": "309"
        },
        {
          "id": "313",
          "nombre": "Esparragos",
          "id_padre": "309"
        },
        {
          "id": "314",
          "nombre": "Muelles",
          "id_padre": "309"
        },
        {
          "id": "312",
          "nombre": "Superior",
          "id_padre": "310"
        },
        {
          "id": "311",
          "nombre": "Inferior",
          "id_padre": "310"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      15,
      [
        {
          "id": "309",
          "nombre": "Estación de Sellado",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "310",
          "nombre": "Placas",
          "id_padre": "309"
        },
        {
          "id": "311",
          "nombre": "Inferior",
          "id_padre": "310"
        },
        {
          "id": "312",
          "nombre": "Superior",
          "id_padre": "310"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      14,
      [
        {
          "id": "334",
          "nombre": "Sistema de Refrigeracion",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "337",
          "nombre": "Partes Electricas",
          "id_padre": "334"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      13,
      [
        {
          "id": "317",
          "nombre": "Estación de Corte",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "320",
          "nombre": "Ventosas",
          "id_padre": "317"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      12,
      [
        {
          "id": "317",
          "nombre": "Estación de Corte",
          "id_padre": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "320",
          "nombre": "Ventosas",
          "id_padre": "317"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ],
    [
      11,
      [
        {
          "id": "320",
          "nombre": "Ventosas",
          "id_padre": "317"
        }
      ],
      "Blister / 0803029 / 21256464"
    ]
  ]
;

//console.log(array);

let array_listado = [];

var contador = {}; //A este objeto les asignamos los ID para irlos contando

for(n in array){
    let conteo = 0;
    let array_prin = array[n][1];
    for(j in array_prin){
        let id_parte = parseInt(array_prin[j].id);
        console.log('id_parte: '+id_parte);

        if(!contador[array_prin[j].id])
            contador[array_prin[j].id] = 1;
        else
            contador[array_prin[j].id]++;

        let result = false;
        for(l in array_listado){
            if(array_listado[l].id === id_parte){
                result = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!result){
            array_listado.push({id: id_parte,nombre: array_prin[j].nombre,conteo: 0,});
        }else{
          //aca no se q hacer :/
          //se supone que debo buscar el elemento y sumarle 1 al contador
        }
    }
}
console.log(array_listado);

for(var id in contador) //Obtenemos los id que se contaron
    console.log("id " + id + " = " + contador[id]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```